# How to configure pool size of Message Driven Bean

Tags: jboss, glassfish, message-driven-bean

I would like to configure the pool size of a MDB but just one.
I deploy my application on JBOSS 6 or Glassfish 3 so the solution must be standard.

I found for JBOSS maxSession for @ActivationConfigProperty but it is not standard 
For glassfish i don't find anything to create sun-ejb-jar.xml ...

Can you help me ?
thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046852/how-to-restrict-pool-size-of-mdb-on-glassfish-v3

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471726/single-threaded-mdb-on-glassfish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For glassfish, you can specify bean's max-pool-size to 1 in glassfish-ejb-jar.xml. See [deployment guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/bearb.html#scrolltoc).

Comment: Thank you ! and for Jboss, do you know to configure jboos with configuaration file ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a sun-ejb-jar.xm which goes in the META-INF folder.

Here's one that you can use / edit.

```
<sun-ejb-jar>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <unique-id>0</unique-id>
        <ejb>
            <ejb-name>YOUR EJB NANME</ejb-name>
            <jndi-name>YOUR JNDI NAME</jndi-name>
            <bean-pool>
                <steady-pool-size>1</steady-pool-size>
                <resize-quantity>1</resize-quantity>
                <max-pool-size>3</max-pool-size>
                <pool-idle-timeout-in-seconds>600</pool-idle-timeout-in-seconds>
            </bean-pool>
        </ejb>
    </enterprise-beans>
</sun-ejb-jar>
```

Comment: I have created glassfish-ejb-jar.xml some your sun-ejb-jar.xml which goes in WEB-INF of my war with web.xml,glassfish-web.xml and everything works ! thank you ! Now i need to configure jboss 6. I have customized ejb3-interceptors-jar.xml with `<annotation expr="class(myclassMDB)">
 @org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Pool (value="StrictMaxPool", maxSize=1, timeout=200000) </annotation>`but i have an exception : `EJBException: Failed to acquire the pool semaphore, strictTimeout=200000` whereas my mdb run in less than 30000ms i would like the same behavior as `@ActivationConfigProperty` with `maxSession`

Answer (score 0):

This is not settable through standard Java EE 6 activation config properties, which are:

- `acknowledgeMode`,
- `messageSelector`,
- `subscriptionDurability`,
- `destinationType`.

All others are provider-specific.

Comment: Thanks !

Is it possible to configure specific server with configuration file ?